# jquery click event doesn't work in appliction, but works in browser's console

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have simple div with `a.close` link. When I click this link it should remove whole `#login-alert` div.
When I enter this `a.close` code to browser's console it works fine, I click `a.close` and `#login-alert` is removed. But it doesn't work when I try the same in my application with below code.

I'm jquery noob, so probably something trivial (ps. this first part pageX, pageY is used for other tasks).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.entry-vote a').click(function(e) {
    pageX = e.pageX;
    pageY = e.pageY;
  });

  $('a.close').click(function(e) {
    $('#login-alert').remove();
  }); 

});
```

Comment: Where is your code located? Is it loaded in the page?

Comment: No, it's generated with jquery.

Answer (score 2):

a.close is most likley an element that gets added after load so you must do this

```
$(document).on('click','a.close',function(){
  $('#login-alert').remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, like I thought it was trivial :/ Time to read some js, jquery books :).